Simple Stateflow model is not functioning
I have designed a basic State-flow model. When I'm trying to run the model, I'm getting an error message
Invalid connection from output port 1 of constant to Input port, Ports are not compatible and cannot be connected to each other

How can I resolve this error?

I tried to modify the port values, but am unable to resolve it.

We will need to know what is coming out of that port in your stateflow, the scope is expecting a scalar input and it looks like you're passing it some kind of bus, which are incompatible as the error states. Please [edit] your question to include more details

@Wolfie The issue is with the constant block on the input side, not the output, but the same applies: we need to how your inputs are defined in your Stateflow chart. Please edit your question and provide more information about the inputs and outputs of the Stateflow chart, and how they've been defined.
